# Nondegenerate 1-periodic solution implies nondegenerate critical point of Hamiltonian

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I started reading through the lecture notes on Floer homology of Dietmar Salamon. The first exercise 1.2 drives me crazy.

---

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, $H$ a time independent Hamiltonian with the Hamiltonian vector field $X_H$, i.e. $\omega(X_H,\cdot)=dH$ and the corresponding flow $\phi:M \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}\phi^t=X_H\circ \phi^t$. I want to show that if $x\in M$ is a critical point of $H$, $\phi^t(x)$ is 1-periodic and $x$ is nondegenerate as 1-periodic solution, i.e. $\det(d_x\phi^1(x)-1)\neq 0$ then $x$ is nondegenerate as critical point of $H$.

---

I tried by just starting of at the Hessian of $H$ at $x$ and trying to show it is nonzero. I know the Hessian on manifolds is defined wrt. to some connection, so i pick an arbitrary almost complex structure $J$ and get a metric wich gives rise to the corresponding Levi-Civita connection. Let $V,W\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ be two vectorfields. I get
$$Hess_x(H)(V,W)=V(W(H))(x)-(\nabla_V W)(H)(x).$$
Since $x$ is a critical point of H, i know that $d_xH=0$, thus $(\nabla_V W)(H)(x)=d_xH(\nabla_V W(x))=0$. Which is nice since now it really doesn't matter what a.c.structure $J$ I picked.
I thought I could get to a Lie-derivative and where I could use the knowledge I have about the flow by the fact that it is a nondegenerate solution.
At critical points the Hessian is symmetric, since $V(W(H))(x)-W(V(H))(x)=[V,W](H)_x=d_xH([V,W]_x)=0$. Just using the symplectic form I don't know where to go
\begin{align}
Hess(H)(V,W)&=V(W(H))\\
 &=V(\omega(X_H,W))\\
\end{align}
That are all my thougts I had. I would love to avoid local charts. Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: This is basically Darboux's theorem. See Proposition 5.4.5 in "Morse Theory and Floer Homology" by Audin for a more "computational" proof similar to what you attempted.

Comment: Yes, I really tried to avoid any local chart. :D But your reference is excellent! The notation is a bit strange but I understood the proof, even if its not intuitive! Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried to read the proof from Audin's book, but I got stuck at the last couple of lines. Can one of you help me out here please? I have linked my question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390525/time-derivative-of-pushforward-equality