# Time derivative of Pushforward equality

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

In Audin and Damian's "Morse Theory and Floer Homology", In Prop. 5.4.5, there is a statement about the time derivative of a pushforward that I am having trouble understanding. In the last two lines of the proof, the following equality is mentioned.
$X_H$ is a Hamiltonian vector field with flow $\psi^t$. $Z$ is a vector in the appropriate tangent space. I don't understand how this equality holds.

$\frac{d}{dt}T_x\psi^t(Z) =  T_x\psi^t([X_H, Z])$

[image: Z is just another vector]

Comment: This looks like the first variation equation. Interchange the $t$ and spatial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this holds for an arbitrary vector field $X$ on the manifold. Denoting by $\psi^t$ its flow, recall that $\psi^{t+s}=\psi^t\circ\psi^s$. Then $$\partial_t\left(\mathrm{d}\psi^t(Z)\right)=\partial_{s=0}\left(\mathrm{d}\psi^{t+s}(Z)\right)=\mathrm{d}\psi^t\partial_{s=0}\left(\mathrm{d}\psi^{s}(Z)\right)=\mathrm{d}\psi^t\left([X,Z]\right)$$
where in the last equality we just used the definition of Lie derivative along a vector field, see for example the definition in terms of flows of the Lie derivative given in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative).

Be careful that, depending on your definition of the Lie derivative, this might actually have the opposite sign.